# Use Vue components inside of Twig without compilating Vue files

Tags: vue.js, symfony, twig

I'm trying to use Vue with my Twig without compilation and CLI since i want it only in one Twig file.

I have `PageComponent.vue` and my twig file`content.twig` i want to include my component into twig file but I don't want to show any scripts inside my twig that's why I'm trying to seperate these files into components

Is this possible to use Vue components without including compilation process?

here is example code of what i'm trying to achieve

```
PageComponent

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <button @click="incrementCounter">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello from Vue component!',
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    incrementCounter() {
      this.counter++;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
app.js

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import PageComponent from "./PageComponent.vue";

const app = createApp({});
app.component('page-component', PageComponent);
app.mount('#app');
```

```
Twig

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>Vue 3 + Twig Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <page-component></page-component>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already tried different approaches to this issue.

before this solution I had everything included in my Twig file, so my html, and Vue added via  tag

Comment: You can't use SFC .vue format without a build step. You need to define templates this way https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn